# How do you change the location of the log files in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, centos6, log-files

I want to be able to access log files from FTP.

FTP home dir: /home/site/

I did this in /etc/my.cnf :

```
long_query_time=2
log-slow-queries=/home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/mysql-log-slow-queries.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes
log_error=/home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/mysql-error.log
```

MySQL-logs folder permissions: 0760
log files permissions: 0660

but with no luck, MySQL won't update new files.

what am I doing wrong?

CENTOS 6.9
MYSQL 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which user is running mysqld?

It is likely that the user who runs mysqld, usually mysql, does not have write access on /home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/

Therefore, it cannot write log files.

Try creating a group for both /home/site/public_html owner and mysql, then chmod 0775 directories and chown  directories

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be that the mysql user does not have access to the home directory of "site". If it can't access it, it can't write to the file either. Even if it has access to write to the mysql-logs directory.

Why don't you just write the logs to /var/log/mysql/ and symlink them instead?

```
cd /home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/
ln -s /var/log/mysql/mysql-log-slow-queries.log
ln -s /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
```

Comment: thanks you, I did that but when I try to open the link in FTP I get "550 Can't open mysql-log-slow-queries.log: No such file or directory
"

Comment: You need to configure the files to log to that specific directory, and restart mysql so it starts writing to the new files. If you get that error message, they most likely do not exist in /var/log/mysql.

Comment: no,I checked. the files exist   root@server1 [/var/log/mysql]# dir
./  ../  mysql-error.log  mysql-log-slow-queries.log

Comment: Could you paste the output of `ls -la /home/site/public_html/mysql-logs` and `ls -la /var/log/mysql` please?

Comment: `ls -la /var/log/mysql
total 166080
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql mysql      4096 Jun 13 11:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root  root       4096 Jun 13 12:51 ../
-rw-r--r--.  1 mysql mysql 155244044 Jun  4 03:41 log-slow-queries.log
-rw-rw----.  1 mysql mysql  14799478 Jun 13 13:01 mysql-log-slow-queries.log`

Comment: `ls -la  /home/site/public_html/mysql-logs
total 24
drwxrw----. 2 site site 4096 Jun 13 11:24 ./
drwxr-x---. 65 site nobody 20480 Jun 12 19:16 ../
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 34 Jun 13 11:24 log-slow-queries.log -> var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 40 Jun 13 11:24 mysql-log-slow-queries.log -> var/log/mysql/mysql-log-slow-queries.log`

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to SELINUX blocking mysql from writing in the `/home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/` path.

Try issuing the following command: `setenforce 0` and to restart mysql. If now the logs can be written, you have found the culprit. However, you should **not** leave SELINUX disabled, as it is a very valuable security asset.

Rather, use `semanage fcontext` to label `/home/site/public_html/mysql-logs/` with the correct type, reenable SELINUX by running `setenforce 1` and restart mysql.